# Capture print dialog's cancel in silverlight printing

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, printing

Does anyone know if you can find out if the print dialog's cancel was clicked?

I've seen post and doc that say "EndPrint – Event fired when the printing is either completed or canceled. "

But I don't think that is the print dialog's canceled... I think the is if the print job is canceled.

thanks

Comment: I'm having issues with this as well. Basically if you cancel out of the print dialog, then the EndPrint event never gets fired. You can see the effects of this here - the code is written to clean up after an EndPrint, but if you cancel instead of actually print, the next time you try, the control thinks you're still printing.

http://www.davidpoll.com/Samples/SLaB/#pack://siteoforigin:,,ScratchPrintingProject.xap/ScratchPrintingProject;component/PrintingPage.xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation, I don't believe there's an easy way:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.printing.printdocument.endprint(v=VS.95).aspx

In particular:

> The EndPrint event will not occur if
>   the user cancels the print operation
>   from the print dialog box. A
>   BeginPrint event will always occur
>   before an EndPrint event.

Apparently the EndPrint event is only to clean up in the case of the document actually printing, not in the case of canceling the print dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way, 
if the 'PrintPage' event is not CALLED after you call 'printDocument.Print()' method that means 'Cancel' button was pressed by the user on print dialog.

hope it helps.