# Silverlight 4 capturing print cancelled

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, printing, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight application that prints out a user control. When the user presses print, the print button is disabled and a status message appears "Printing page {number}." It works fine except if you cancel the printing job the EndPrint event never gets fired.

Is there a way to capture the on printing cancel event?

Comment: I've run into this too. Just looked at it quickly, but it seems that's not supported. A similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803967/capture-print-dialogs-cancel-in-silverlight-printing

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I had to put off my busy indicator OFF either on a successful print or cancel.

If you see the following statement

```
printDocument.Print()
```

this method is not an asynchronous call to your dialog. When this statement executes, the print dialog opens up. Unless n until that dialog is not closed (by clicking print or cancel), the control doesn't go to the next statement. So following how I solved my problem:

```
TurnBusyIndicator(ON)
printDocument.Print()
TurnBusyIndicator(OFF)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello well several months ago i worked with silverlight 4 printing api, to catch any errors or cancellations on the printing queue i just added the following line to my print process

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
....
pd.EndPrint += (s, args) =>
    {
      //Handle possilbe print errors or post print stuff here (wich you can see in args
    };
```

also as posted on documentation the EndPrint event will not occur if the user cancels the print operation from the print dialog box (in this case BeginPrint never was raised). A BeginPrint event will always occur before an EndPrint event (http://bit.ly/ho0kKE) also take in account the browser you are using, there is a big diff between supported vs "it works" :)

hope this helps

Alex